# SQL query WHERE clause to have entries from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks something like this

```
DocumentID AttributeID LongValue StringValue BooleanValue
100                 1                 null                null                 1
100                 2                 123                 null                 null
100                 3                 null                test                 null
```

Each attributeID is of a type and only that column is filled and everything else is null. A document can have multiple attributes.

My query demands that I find document where

```
Attribute ID 1 has value 1
Attribute ID 2 has value 123
Attribute ID 3 has value test
```

I was writing a query like this

```
select documentID
from table
where (
    (AttributeID=1 AND BooleanValue=1) AND
    (AttributeID=2 AND LongValue=123) AND
    (AttributeID=3 AND StringValue="test"))
```

The above query, obviously, is giving me zero results although document 100 satisfies my constraints. 
How do I change my query to get document ID 100 as the result?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  DocumentID
FROM    tablename
WHERE   (AttributeID = 1 AND booleanValue = 1) OR
        (AttributeID = 2 AND longValue = 123) OR
        (AttributeID = 3 AND stringValue = 'test')
GROUP   BY DocumentID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't this query return a document if it matches any one of the attribute value? Also, the count can be dynamic, need not be 3.

Comment: @user2812714 nope. it will only show `documentID` if it has meet the three conditions in the `WHERE` clause. The `HAVING` clause filters `documentID` which are equal to 3 since you have specified three conditions in the `WHERE` clause. for *dynamic*, create a procedure or something that sets the value from a parameter.